# Toolbar contains text from action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

There is two styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="Caribbean" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/caribbeanButton</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

The second one is set as a `Activity` theme in manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ui.Activity"
        android:theme="@style/Caribbean">

    </activity>
```

And there is `Toolbar` in `ConstraintLayout`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            style="@style/ToolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cash_out" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I try to apply this `Toolbar` as an `ActionBar`

```
Toolbar toolbar = binding.toolbar;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

After that what I can see is a Toolbar with added `TextView` in the center and `AppCompatTextView` from the  `ActionBar`  left to the centered text with application name.

I tried to use `setTitle("")`, but it didn't help.

What could be the reason of this problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to make the toolbar's text disappear?

Comment: The title says "Toolbar contains text from action bar"
The op wants to set title for his toolbar... he also stated "I tried to use setTitle(""), but it didn't help"

Comment: @PedroBranco you're right, thank you. @aborocz , want to make `ActionBar` title disapear

Comment: change your theme to parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove `ConstraintLayout` from your `xml` and use
>   `getSupportActionBar.setTitle("")`

Comment: My bad, I just needed to add `getSupportActionBar.setTitle("")` after setting toolbar. There wasn't need to remove ConstraintLayout